# setTimeout(myFunction, 5000); vs setTimeout(myFunction(), 5000);

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I was playing around with the "setTimeout" function. This code runs like expected:

```
function myFunction() {
    console.log('test');
    setTimeout(myFunction, 1000);
}
myFunction();
```

It prints every second 'test' to the console.

But when running this code the timeout is not waiting:

```
function myFunction() {
    console.log('test');
    setTimeout(myFunction(), 1000);
}
myFunction();
```

And it spams my console with 'test'.

The only difference in code are the brackets of myFunction() call. Why is this happening?

Comment: The second version makes sense only if `myFunction()` returns a function.

Comment: or returns a string that can be evaluated to a valid function invokation: `const f = () => "console.log(123)"; setTimeout(f(), 1000);`

Answer (score 3):

That is because by including the parentheses you're actually *executing* the function and passing its *result* to `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 3):

`myFunction()` calls the function **immediately** and passes its return value to `setTimeout` to be called later (except its return value is `undefined`, which isn't a function (or a string), so that is pointless).

Answer (score 2):

`setTimeout(myFunction(), 1000);` means that your pass result returned by myFunction()  as the 1st argument of setTimeout. myFunction returns nothing, so `setTimeout(myFunction(), 1000);` is the same as `setTimeout(undefined, 1000);`

Answer (score 0):

`myfunction()` passes its return value to "SetTimeOut" and execute:
`setTimeout( RetunValue , 1000)`  then error...

`myfunction` execute the procedure attached to it

prints "Test" on the console